# How to use valdr AngularJS form validation service with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, valdr

I've been checking out the valdr form validation service (http://netceteragroup.github.io/valdr/) as means of better organizing my form validation rules. It looks quite simple to use, except I think it has issue supporting ng-repeat blocks.

This because it relies on input name attribute to map rules to inputs, but by dynamically building inputs within an ng-repeat, the input names change.

Wondered if anyone had experience with this? Also curious of any feedback in general for this plugin, since there is little mention of it out on the web.

Thank you.

Comment: You can have inputs with the same name. I would guess it will work with `ng-form`.

Comment: Wasn't aware of ng-form directive (still getting familiar with Angular). I will read up on that. Thx.

Comment: I've found this example with `ng-repeat` and `ng-form` on their github: https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr/blob/master/demo/core/list.html